# Compare a cell with a column and returns True if they contain at least a common character in GOOGLE SHEET

Tags: google-sheets

I would like it to return true in C1 if A1 and B1 have at least one common character and return false in C2 if A2 and B1 do not have any common character

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [1, 7, 12] | 1, 8, 9, 40 |  |
| 2 | [10, 15, 22] |  |  |
| 3 | [1, 15, 121, 10] |  |  |

```
=INDEX(REGEXMATCH(A1:A3, "\b"&SUBSTITUTE(B1:B3, ",", "|")&"\b"))
```

Comment: please do share a sample editable sheet if possible (showcasing the expected output as well)

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please edit your question to insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 0):

Remove spaces and use a capturing group, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  regexmatch( 
    A1:A3, 
    "\b(" & regexreplace( trim(B1), "\s*,\s*", "|" ) & ")\b" 
  ) 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(REGEXMATCH(A1:A3, "\b("&SUBSTITUTE(B1, ",", "|")&")\b"))
```

[image]

Comment: It did not work correctly

Comment: @ShahparSattar share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output